# An idiom or expression to describe an atmosphere where everyone in the group is in a creative mode

Tags: idioms, expressions

I am looking for an idiom or an expression to describe a creative vibe in a group. Here is what I mean by a creative vibe:

"The group feels elated, lively and in good spirits. They want to go beyond the existing solutions and boundaries. Their minds idle freely and diverge in alternatives. Everyone is actively thinking of new ideas. Inspiration is ready to be triggered. The group is open to receive any input that is new and interesting. There is a joint effort to create. Humour and jokes create a comfortable and non-judgmental environment for self expression. The members builds upon each other’s ideas playfully."

As an idiom I thought of " heads in the clouds" but that means daydreaming and thinking out of reality, as far as I understood. I want to find an idiom which can work for being creative in the process of generating ideas while handling a real-life issue. Secondly, I thought of " creative juices are flowing", but I prefer not to use the word creative in the idiom/ expression itself. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I think your choice of *creative vibe* is an excellent choice.  I knew what you meant from your first sentence.  Many people like to associate creativity with a *muse* or a *creative muse*.   Feel free build your own metaphor.   Answers here may be opinion based.

Comment: You might be able to work the word "energized" in there somewhere.

Comment: You could use the colloquial expression [firing on all cylinders](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-firing-on-all-cylinders).  That means "working at peak effectiveness," which is not specific to creativity, but if you say it in the context of a group that has creativity as part of its job, then it's clear from the context that includes all aspects of creativity.